# what does these output mean?

Tags: linux, bash

especially the last two with '-' and '+' respectively,
what does it mean on earth?

```
[1]   Done                    php start.php bots/admin32.bot.php

[2]   Done                    php start.php bots/admin36.bot.php

[3]   Done                    php start.php bots/admin10.bot.php

[4]   Done                    php start.php bots/admin11.bot.php

[5]   Done                    php start.php bots/admin13.bot.php

[6]   Done                    php start.php bots/admin3.bot.php

[7]-  Done                    php start.php bots/admin4.bot.php

[8]+  Done                    php start.php bots/admin7.bot.php

[root@www2 robot]#
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Just an easy experiment: sleep 1s & sleep 1s & sleep 1s &, then wait and press return

Answer (score 8):

From the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control-Basics),

> Job number `n` may be referred to as ‘`%n`’. The symbols ‘`%%`’ and ‘`%+`’ refer to the shell's notion of the current job, which is the last job stopped while it was in the foreground or started in the background. A single ‘`%`’ (with no accompanying job specification) also refers to the current job. The previous job may be referenced using ‘`%-`’. If there is only a single job, ‘`%+`’ and ‘`%-`’ can both be used to refer to that job. In output pertaining to jobs (e.g., the output of the jobs command), the current job is always flagged with a ‘`+`’, and the previous job with a ‘`-`’.

In Bash's output when starting and stopping jobs,

> `[n]+` *status*

means "job `%n` (aka job `%+`) is now *status*".

Answer (score 1):

I think your command contains the character `&`, which is causing the command to run in the background. When the command finishes, it prints this output.

Example:

```
$ echo 1 &
[1] 16021
$
[1]+  Done                    echo 1
```

To prevent this from happening, quote the `&` character. It's probably part of a URL in your case, so you can use:

```
$ wget "http://www.example.com/index.php?a=1&b=2"
```

As for the `+` and `-` signs, they refer to the current and previous jobs respectively. See this page on [job control in bash](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC91) for more info.

Comment: when you talk about it as it's done,

do you mean the process died ?

but I used ps -ef only to find it's still alive.

Comment: When the word 'Done' is printed, it means that the process is finished executing. You probably have many processes running the same command or something.

Comment: `ps -e` shows all processes on the system.  For only those belong to your current session, use plain `ps` (`ps -H` gives you a tree view).